# Get all the nodes with matching taxonomy terms in a view Display

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a view which shows all the page elements.

So, in five displays of view, it shows Hero area, description, sidebar etc.

The last display has to show all the nodes which has similar taxonomy terms of this current node.

For example, if Taxonomy is `Interests`, and I have selected `Basketball`, `Chess`, `Baseball`, then I am hoping to output all nodes with the same interests.

I am trying here to get all nodes within my display. Is it possible?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you have a view of content each with references to the taxonomy vocabulary `Interests`. If this is the case, then you can easily add a *filter* to your view with the selected terms in that taxonomy.

To allow users to select which term elements render on the page, make it an exposed filter (perhaps select or multiselect).